# Не могу понять как работает pygame.time.set_timer()

Tags: python, pygame

Я создаю игру на библиотеке pygame простенькую.Суть игры в том что космический корабль летает и сбивает пришельцев. Так вот я хочу добавить, чтобы у корабля была перезарядка.
Как я понял для этого лучше всего подходит set_timer(). Пожалуйста объясните какие три аргумента должны быть в нем. Я понял ,что второй аргумент это время в милисекундах, а первый и третий вообще не понимаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так в доки загляните. И приведите ваш код.

Comment: Ты уже посмотрел документацию и не нашел ответа?

Comment: сайт у них не работает

Comment: так бы я посмотрел. Мне просто нужно обьяснение как работает set_timer()

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer

Comment: @S.Nick у меня тоже сайт не работает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056444/pygame-time-set-timer-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый аргумент event является событием, которое будет появляться каждое заданное количество миллисекунд (второй аргумент). Третий аргумент loop  - целое число, обозначающее сколько раз это событие будет появляться. По умолчанию loop = 0. Это значит, что событие будет появляться все время, пока его не отменят другой функцией set.timer(), в которую нужно передать вторым аргументом 0.
Вот работающая ссылка на документацию: https://pg1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer